# How do I show that $T_{2n}=(M_n+T_n)/{2}$ where $M_n$ and $T_n$ are midpoint and trapexium estimates?

Tags: calculus, integration

> Given a definite integral $I$, let $M_k$ and $T_k$ be the midpoint and trapezium estimates using $k$ strips.  Show that $T_{2n}=\frac{M_n+T_n}{2}$ for all $n\ge 1$.

I find it difficult to solve, can you help me please?

Comment: It's okay if you're not good at LaTeX.  Just read the FAQ, where we show you how to do it.  If you aren't willing to put the time into learning that, I'm not willing to put the time in to answer your question.

Comment: ok...i'll do my best to learn it

Comment: Alright!  [Here is the tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/12952).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a verbal way of describing what is going on.

The Trapezium estimate $T_n$ says weight the values
by 1 at all the internal grid points
and by 1/2 at the endpoints.

The midpoint estimate $M_n$ says to weight all the values
at the midpoints of each interval equally.

In both of these, the sum of the weights is $n$,
$(n-1)\times 1 + 2\times (1/2)$ for $T_n$
and
$n \times 1$ for $M_n$.

Let's see what happens when
we go from $n$ to $2n$
and compute $T_{2n}$.
The intervals are now half the size,
so we get all the points
used in computing $T_n$
and $M_n$. 
The weights are 1 at all the interior points
and 1/2 at the endpoints.

Now look at $(T_n+M_n)/2$.
All the interior points have weight 1
(all the points used in $M_n$ are interios)
and the endpoints have weight 1/2 
(from $T_n$).
But this is exactly the same weights
as for $T_{2n}$.